# position: sticky doesn't work when virtual keyboard is open in Safari

Tags: css, safari

Position sticky doesn't work when virtual keyboard is open in Safari

I've tried using `position: -webkit-sticky`.

Expected behavior in non-Safari webkit browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera)

```
.sticky {
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open https://codepen.io/wmsmacdonald/pen/vYBVVRL in Safari on iOS
2. Scroll to bring white screen into viewport
3. Click text input to focus

Expected:
Red footer should stick to bottom of screen even when virtual keyboard is open
Actual:
User must scroll down with keyboard open in order to see the red footer

Answer (score 6):

```
let pendingUpdate = false;
const viewportHandler = (event) => {
    if (pendingUpdate) {
        return;
    }
    pendingUpdate = true;

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        pendingUpdate = false;
        const layoutViewport = document.querySelector('.sticky');
        layoutViewport.style.transform = "none";
        if (layoutViewport.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0) {
            layoutViewport.style.transform = `translate(0, ${-layoutViewport.getBoundingClientRect().top}px)`;
        }
    });
};
window.visualViewport.addEventListener("scroll", viewportHandler);
window.visualViewport.addEventListener("resize", viewportHandler);
```

The `pendingUpdate` flag serves to prevent multiple invocations of the transfrom that can occur when onresize and onscroll fire at the same time. Using `requestAnimationFrame()` ensures that the transform occurs before the next render.

Answer (score 5):

This is expected behavior in Safari as of October 2019:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202120

A workaround to make it consistent with other rendering engines would be to use the [Visual Viewport API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API) to get the visual viewport height and fix the element to the bottom using position: absolute.  However, the Visual Viewport API only has support in Safari 13.